# Get a child project property

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application ("myapp") that uses an Android library ("mylib").
I need to get mylib build.gradle versionCode from the application build.gradle.

This is what I have for now:

mylib's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 42
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

myapp's settings.gradle:

```
include ':myapp', ':mylib'
```

myapp's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode project(":mylib").versionCode
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But Gradle outputs the error:

> Could not find property 'versionCode' on project ':mylib'

Do you have any idea?